# Responsive SVG polygon with relative points

Tags: svg, polygon

How do I create a SVG polygon which is responsive/scalable in width, but contains relative points which must stay in place at the peak points?

This shows what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image]

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: What's supposed to happen when the height changes? Does it clip? If so you'll need to do the responsiveness yourself by catching resize events and working out what to draw where.

Comment: The height should stay static (i.e. 100px), if that's what you mean?

Comment: hard to do in SVG then.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to iterate relative points and normalize the unique view's width and height pixels.

```
var originalPointsString = '0,0 0,1 1,1 1,0 0,0'; //points to a square
var newPointsStr = '';
forEach(originalPointsString.split(' '), function(point){
    var x = point.split(',')[0], // gets the x coord from each point
        y = point.split(',')[1]; // gets the y coord from each point
    var hPx = Math.floor((window.innerWidth / 100) * x), // gets how many pixels per percent in a given view's width
        vPx = Math.floor((window.innerHeight / 100) * y); // gets how many pixels per percent in a given view's height
    newPointsStr += hPx +','+vPx+' '; // build new point coords based on the normalized view percents
})
// Given example 1000px x 500px view
// newPointsStr === '0,0 0,5 10,5 10,0 0,0'
```

This will be responsive on load but you'll have to work other magicks to watch for window resize.

Comment: I use a function that takes the originalPointsString from an object with coords property and each polygon goes through that function.